Split Mongo Db array into multiple documents
I have the following Document in my colletion
{
  "_id": "12345",
  "Products": [
    "Product1",
    "Product2"
  ],
  "State": "active",
}

How do I project it into multiple documents based on the array? The required output should be like this
{
  "_id": "12345",
  "Product": "Product1",
  "State": "active",
}

{
  "_id": "12345",
  "Product": "Product2",
  "State": "active",
}


Just { "$unwind": "$Products" } and $project.

Use the aggregate stage $unwind.


$unwind - Deconstruct the Products array into multiple documents.

$set - Set the Product field with Products and remove the Products field.


db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Products"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Product: "$Products",
      Products: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground
